# NSArray of NSString to NSString of NSArray literal?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, converters, literals

For example I have the following array:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"string1", @"string2", @"string3"];
```

I need to get string:

```
@"@[@"string1", @"string2", @"string3"]"
```

The reason is simple - when you receive the array values somewhere from remote server it takes some time. But you could find this string to test the app behaviour offline.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand why you would need literal like that. I think when you get array from server you get it as json.

Comment: What I get is you need transform the array into JSON?

Comment: to Krzysztof, maybe you are right. But the problem is even in this case server may return both json and xml (and even plain text) and I also may take the response as both data and string format. Finally not only server generate "dynamic" arrays but for example a library with hidden code. So your case is too particular.

Comment: to childrenOurFuture, where do you see "JSON" in this question? And stop downvote please if you don't want even to understand the question

Comment: He's assumed JSON as that's pretty much what you are asking for.  What you wrote in your question isn't JSON, but is very close. iOS has built-in JSON conversion classes, which makes it easy to convert between a string and an array/dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@[@\"%@\"]", [arr componentsJoinedByString:@"\", @\""]]
```

So when I run code for the first time I print the values from array with this line. This line is enough complex to remember but enough easy to paste and use even in console with `po` command.

Then I just copy this line from console and assign it to my array.

Maybe does someone know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to simulate getting JSON from a server? If that's what your goal is, put everything that you need into an `NSDictionary` as when you get the JSON from the server the chances are, you would be serializing it into an `NSDictionary`.

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"string1", @"string2", @"string3"];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{@"myArray" : arr};
```

Comment: Instead of one simple string you suggest to get a dictionary, serialize, deserialize it each time and... I didn't mentioned json in my question at all - it could be any format and even plain text.

Comment: Why would you actually want them to be literal strings in the array? why  not "string1, string2, string3"? Please can you give a little more information about the usage?

Comment: I get a literal. Then I copy this value into my code and get a proxy. One small change and I don't need to access to server to test the same values